# Return bounty to questions that get no answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why aren’t bounties refunded if they are not awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56298/why-arent-bounties-refunded-if-they-are-not-awarded)

What is the reasoning behind destroying rep on a bounty question that receives no acceptable answers or no answers at all.  If a bounty question receives no answers after 7 days, you should be able to increase the bounty, adding to the unclaimed bounty.

Comment: Most of this is discussed over at [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56298/why-arent-bounties-refunded-if-they-are-not-awarded-closed). A bounty is paying for 7 days of increased exposure, you're not paying the people who answer it. They just get a winning if they do answer within the period. It's also never going to be a guarantee of an answer.

Comment: This should be made clear as a note in the bounty option itself.