# Bounty re-assign?

Tags: support, expired-bounty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)
>   [Why aren't bounties refunded if they are not awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56298/why-arent-bounties-refunded-if-they-are-not-awarded)
>   [“Abusing” bounties for unlimited profit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit)

I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243029/exporting-to-csv-encoding-problems#) question to which I started a bounty of +50. Nothing drastically changed about it, no actually better answers and the bounty period ended.

Now I know if there is an +2 answer it will be automatically be rewarded with the bounty. Not the case here. So the bounty just disappeared.

Now I want to start a +200 bounty because this is a critical question for me, but as long as the +50 bounty wasn't awarded to anyone yet, shouldn't I be able to re-assign it to my current  bounty and make it a +250 bounty ?

Hope this is pretty clear. Any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 7):

> Now I want to start a +200 bounty because this is a critical question for me, but as long as the +50 bounty wasn't awarded to anyone yet, shouldn't I be able to re-assign it to my current bounty and make it a +250 bounty ?

No.

The principal function of a bounty is to draw attention to your question (just like any other paid ad).

Even if you don't get the answer you needed, you still got the extra attention, which is what you *paid* for.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense. This could turn into an abuse. +1