# Where is my bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should bounty be returned if there is NO answer at all?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21609/should-bounty-be-returned-if-there-is-no-answer-at-all)

Why was my bounty deducted, even though I haven't got any single suitable answer? It should be returned back to the user, who started the bounty.

I visited some queries posted by Jeff Attwood and other guys but didn't find it satisfactory. Please help me in returing the bounty and change the bounty distribution policy.

Comment: Read the small print next time! Hahahahaah!

Comment: this is just ridiculuos. From the above and below comments one thing I realize is that you guys are trying to say that " You went to a shop, you offered the shopkeeper, i will pay you just for entering the shop and talking to you, instead you provide me what i want.".... hahahahahahahahahahahahahahhahah... coool feature...

Answer (score 5):

It's big and fat in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> In any case, you will always give up the amount of reputation specified in the bounty, so if you start a bounty, be sure to follow up and award your bounty to the best answer!

Also you get notified - multiple times, I think - that the bounty amount is lost in any case.

Changing that aspect of the system has been suggested, discussed and declined a number of times for several reasons. You can read up on it here on Meta in the `bounty` tag.

Answer (score 2):

### [Bounties and non-valid answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21669/bounties-and-non-valid-answers/21687#21687)

> Bottom Line: The bounty is to generate interest and answers for your question, it does not necessarily guarantee that one of those will be the right answer.

### [Should bounty be returned if there is NO answer at all?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21609/should-bounty-be-returned-if-there-is-no-answer-at-all/21689#21689)

> Consider bounties to be paying for advertising. Once you've purchased an ad spot, you can't get your money back just because no one bought your product.

### [Why aren’t bounties refunded if they are not awarded? [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56298/why-arent-bounties-refunded-if-they-are-not-awarded/56305#56305)

> Also, if it becomes obvious that your question is unclear then you should edit it for clarity. This has the added bonus of popping you to the top of the active list as well, which would generate extra interest.

If after adding a bounty, you are still unable to get a valid answer to your question, perhaps your question is unclear or unanswerable. You should be editing the question to incorporate *any* feedback you have received from users.

### [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> **What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?**
>   **What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered?**
>   **What is automatic awarding?**
>
> At the end of the bounty period, if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, eligible answers can be automatically awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an answer to be eligible for automatic awarding are as follows:
>
> ```
> * The answer must be given after the bounty was started
> * The answer must have a score of at least +2
> ```
>
> If two or more eligible answers have the same score, the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.
>
> If no answers meet these criteria, the bounty ends without it being awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if you get paid for your answers here :-p

Comment: @Andy If I was getting paid to work here, then I'd spend all my work hours coding C#. But thank you! I appreciate the compliment! Hopefully Jeff will take note and offer me a job :p