# What are my choices when I don't receive any correct answers for my bounty question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, answers, bounties

I've asked a question on Stack Overflow with a bounty. Assume I have received three answers, but all of them are incorrect and not what I asked. I clearly mentioned what my problem was and what I'm trying to achieve, yet I didn't received any correct answers.

What are my choices if I don't get any answers with in next three days? I have spent almost half of my points on that question around 300. I just don't want to waste my points to incorrect answers and not useful answers.

Can we ask moderators for help? Explain my situation. As a small user with just around 500 points I don't want to waste it for an incorrect answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bounties and non-valid answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21669/bounties-and-non-valid-answers) also see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49394/what-if-i-offer-a-bounty-and-dont-get-any-good-answers and the column "Related" on the right.

Comment: You can post comments beneath the answers explaining why the supplied solutions do not work. If the answers are really off-the-mark, then downvote them. The answer with the most upvotes, posted during the bounty period, is awarded half  of the sum offered if the OP fails to award the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Assume I have received 3 answers but all of them are incorrect and not what I asked. I clearly mentioned what my problem was and what I'm trying to achieve yet I didn't received any correct answers.

If you have received three answers, and all of them are incorrect, then it doesn’t sound like your question is actually all that clear.  If those three answers are radically different it sounds like three different users all read your question and determine you wanted three different things.

I was unable to find any question in which you offered 300 reputation on Stack Overflow.  The only question I was able to find was a single bounty worth 50 but you selected an answer in that case last year.

> I want to know what are my choices if I don't get any answers with in next three days?

The bounty you offered was nonrefundable.  You were made aware of this when you offered it.  The fact you got three answers which you have decided are not helpful doesn’t change anything.  In fact, if you had received zero answers, the bounty would still not be refundable.

> Can we ask moderators for help? Explain my situation. As a small user with just around 500 points I don't want to waste it for incorrect answer.

Your situation will not meet the very limited cases where a bounty is refundable, which is basically limited to the case, where a question should be closed.

You are welcome to raise a custom flag but you should not expect the bounty to be refunded.  You were warned it wasn’t refundable, the fact you offered more reputation then the minimum amount, was your choice.

Comment: @SaiKumar - You are not guaranteed an answer when you offer a bounty.  I stand by my comment that if your getting three different answers then the question isn’t as clear as you believe it to be. **You can answer your own question, but you cannot award the bounty to yourself, the bounty is not refundable.**